# Using PHP to send this email form?

Tags: php, html

I have the following code for an email form from an HTML template. I'd like to make it send email, as the moment I think it doesn't and I need to add some PHP to process the form. Any tips on how to do that for this form?

Thank you!

```
<!-- Email -->
<article id="email" class="panel">
    <header>

<h2>Email Me</h2>

    </header>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <div class="5grid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="6u">
                    <input type="text" class="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="6u">
                    <input type="text" class="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="12u">
                    <input type="text" class="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="12u">
                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="12u">
                    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send Message" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</article>
```

Comment: You [just asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576861/making-an-email-form-send-email)

Comment: phpmailer?  `mail(...)`?  Have you googled this?

Comment: well the person in the previous question told me to ask a new question

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and https://www.google.ca/search?q=php%20mail%28%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a should get you started ;-)

Comment: Read this before posting question next time: [how to ask question: the smart way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: thanks for the link fred! i guess i can directly use the input from the html based on the name, didn't realize that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php

so you get your data with `$_POST` and then treated data, to use something like this:

```
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
mail('myMail@example.com', 'subject', $message);
```